# CreateIndexBuffer() crashes,some kind of pointer error.What could be causing this?

Tags: pointers, null, directx, buffer, direct3d

I get

```
Unhandled exception at 0x004687b4 in D3DTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

the error is at:

```
m_d3dDevice->CreateIndexBuffer(sizeof(short)*CHUNK_PRIMITIVES*3,D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY, D3DFMT_INDEX16, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &m_ib, NULL);
```

Now I checked **m_d3dDevice** and it's all OK,everything works properly if I don't create the buffer.
**m_ib** is also propery created before being used in that function:

```
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 m_vb;
    m_vb = NULL;
```

I don't think anything else could be causing the problem.I'm confused.

Comment: You only show the m_vb setup, but I imagine m_ib is similar. Need to see more of the code really.

Comment: So far code looks good. Could you please give more extended code sample? Btw, `D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY` doesn't make sense when you explicitly specify memory class (`D3DPOOL_MANAGED`). Try specifying `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT` and check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the debug runtime from the DirectX control panel that will show you warnings and errors if you have any and always check the return codes from DX functions.

Showing the code for the whole function that creates the index buffer would help too.